# Flexible divs that grow and shrink depending on the number of divs in that container

Tags: html, css, response

I have a project where I have one set width container at 600px. Inside that container will be any number of divs (with rounded corners to look like circles). If there is anywhere between 1-3 divs in the container, they should be centered with a max height and width of 160px. But as soon as theres more than three they drop down to another row, I don't want this. I need the divs to be flexible and be able to shrink in size to accommodate more divs, all on the same row.

Hopefully this makes sense, I've attached an image for help explaining. I would LOVE to do this with just CSS.

[image]

Comment: i guess you can do something with media-queries but your wrapper div needs to be fluid and not fixed width,  try some javascript for less tricky way

Comment: check this out: http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/132-quick-useful-case-sass-math-mixins/?play=true

Comment: So if you have 10 child elements in you 600px wide parent container, each child would have a width of 60px...???

Comment: @MarcAudet You are correct, width AND height of 60px in that case. But they most likely will have some margin on them too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like display:flex; **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vCltD)**

So On parent, you just need to use : `display:flex;` and `justify-content:center;`
the child can be sized and be set to  `align-self: shrink;` in order to shrink down .

`display:table;`+ `display:table-cell;` with 2 empty pseudos element as `display:table-cell` , in order to center a single div can be done too : **[DEMO 2](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FxIqf)**

Comment: This is great! The first example is just what I was looking for!